# Pattern Matching Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, csv

```
create table monument(ID int primary key,monument varchar(100);

insert into monument values(1,'Taj,Paris');
insert into monument values(2,'Taj');
insert into monument values(3,'Tajmahal,Gateway');
insert into monument values(4,'Burjkhalifa,Gateway of India');
```

Assuming I'm passing parameters as 'Taj,Gate',hence I need all the rows where  monument contains either Taj or Gate in the string.

Comment: ya...
basically i can have comma separated values in both the array fields.The left array is the column of a table which will return if it contains any value from the comma separated values on the right

Comment: Why do you have a comma separate value in an array? That doesn't make sense. You should put each "separated value" into its own array element.

Comment: We are storing these values against a Primary Key column & need to filter out those IDs which match against comma separated input parameter

Comment: Question edited with structure as required...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform a search query on a column value containing a string with command separated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714700/how-to-perform-a-search-query-on-a-column-value-containing-a-string-with-command)

Answer (score 1):

Storing comma separated values in a single column is a huge design mistake to begin with.

You need to convert the varchar values to arrays to be able to treat the CSV value as separated elements:

```
select *
from monument m
where string_to_array(m.monument, ',') && string_to_array('Taj,Gate', ',');
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/BJRTM46696